# SQL Server, Order by reference data column

Tags: sql-server

I have `Employee` table with columns `FirstName`, `LastName`, `DepartmentId` and a `MasterLookup` table with fields `Id`, `Category, Value`. I also have a `Department` table, which has the following values. *(Note this table has values for more than one category. i.e Department and MaritalStatus.)*

```
1   Department      Human Resources
2   Department      Accounting
3   Department      Operations
4   MaritalStatus   Married
5   MaritalStatus   Single
```

I wanted to list all employees from the Employee table with their departments sorted in ascending order like this

```
FirstName..  Accounting
FirstName... Accounting
FirstName... Human Resources
FirstName... Operations
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT FirstName, DepartmentName 
FROM Employee Emp
LEFT OUTER JOIN MasterLookup Lookup ON Emp.DepartmentId = Lookup.Id
Orderby ????
```

Can this be done using dynamic query?

Comment: order by firstname, department_name

Comment: MasterLookup will have more than one Category. In this example two categories Department and MaritalStatus

Comment: @Raj Did you try `ORDER BY Dept.DepartmentName ASC`?

Comment: It isn't clear why `MasterLookup` comes into play. You also didn't list the column names for the `Department` table. Third, is there a particular reason you think a left join is required?

Comment: You somehow messed up the explanation of your tables. The table you are showing seems to be the key / value table, not the department table. But if you have a department table, what would you need key /value entries for departments for?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake I update the SELECT query using MasterLookup table

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to list all employees from the Employee table with their departments sorted in ascending

So order by the `DepartmentName` column:

```
SELECT Emp.FirstName, Dept.DepartmentName 
FROM Employee Emp
LEFT OUTER JOIN Department Dept ON Emp.DepartmentId = Dept.DepartmentId
ORDER BY Dept.DepartmentName ASC;
```